# How To Loop Sequence of Loaded SWF Files?

Tags: loops, flash, load, sequence

***READY!*** Here it is : We have a simple but useful code that loads 2 swf files in sequence ...

**But How can I Loop it?**

How can you change the code to load swf1 after swf2 is finished?

I've tried almost the **whole day** but no result yet... Please help...Even with your **comments** any any any idea is greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot...

*Here is the code:*

```
import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.loading.*;
import com.greensock.events.LoaderEvent;
import flash.events.Event;


//create SWFLoaders


var swf1:SWFLoader = new SWFLoader("child1.swf",{container:this,y:100,onProgress:progressHandler,onComplete:completeHandler,autoPlay:false});
var swf2:SWFLoader = new SWFLoader("child2.swf",{container:this,y:100,onProgress:progressHandler,onComplete:completeHandler,autoPlay:false});
var currentSWFLoader:SWFLoader = swf1;


//adjust the progress bar;
function progressHandler(e:LoaderEvent):void {
    bar.scaleX = e.target.progress;
    trace(e.target.progress);
}


//tell the loaded swf to play and start tracking frames
function completeHandler(e:LoaderEvent):void {
    //the target of the LoaderEvent is the SWFLoader that fired the event
    //the rawContent is the loaded swf
    e.target.rawContent.play();
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkFrame);
}


function checkFrame(e:Event):void {
    //check to see if loaded swf is done playing
    if (currentSWFLoader.rawContent.currentFrame == currentSWFLoader.rawContent.totalFrames) {
        trace("swf done playing");
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkFrame);


        //if the first swf is done playing load the second swf
        if (currentSWFLoader == swf1) {
            currentSWFLoader.dispose(true) // dispose and unload content
            currentSWFLoader = swf2;
            currentSWFLoader.load();
        }
    }
}


bar.scaleX = 0;
currentSWFLoader.load();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need **OOP** approach.

First, create a class that completely handles one external SWF: loading, playing, signaling the end of playback, unloading and cleaning up.

```
package
{
    // Imports.
    import flash.events.Event;

    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class ExternalMovie extends Sprite
    {
        private var L:Loader;
        private var M:MovieClip;

        // Handles loading.
        public function loadAndPlay(url:String):void
        {
            L = new Loader;
            addChild(L);

            L.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onLoaded);
            L.load(new URLRequest(url));
        }

        // Handles Loader.contentLoaderInfo event Event.INIT.
        private function onLoaded(e:Event):void
        {
            L.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.INIT, onLoaded);

            // Get a direct reference to the loaded movie root.
            M = L.content as MovieClip;

            // Set up the watchdog for loaded movie to finish.
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onWatch);
        }

        // Event.ENTER_FRAME handler to watch the loaded movie playback.
        private function onWatch(e:Event):void
        {
            if (M.currentFrame >= M.totalFrames)
            {
                M.stop();

                // Announce the end of playback.
                dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
            }
        }

        // Unloads movie and cleans up.
        public function dispose():void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onWatch);

            L.unloadAndStop(true);

            removeChild(L);

            L = null;
            M = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Second, compose a controlling script, that makes an instance of that class, tells it to play SWF by its URL, then waits for the end of playback and moves on to the next movie.

```
import ExternalMovie;

var EML:ExternalMovie;

var current:int = -1;
var plan:Array = ["child1.swf", "child2.swf"];

// Start the first one manually.
playNext();

function playNext(e:Event = null):void
{
    // Clean up the last one, if any.
    if (EML)
    {
        removeChild(EML);

        EML.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, playNext);
        EML.dispose();
        EML = null;
    }

    // Switch to next url.
    current++;

    // Loop from the beginning if last movie just played.
    if (current >= plan.length)
    {
        current = 0;
    }

    // Get the next movie URL.
    var nextURL:String = plan[current];

    EML = new ExternalMovie;

    // Subscribe to Event.COMPLETE event to know the exact moment the
    // current movie finished playing to remove it and load the next one.
    EML.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, playNext);
    EML.loadAndPlay(nextURL);

    addChild(EML);
}
```

Keep in mind that all of above is more of a guideline than a complete working solution (although it just **might** work).

Comment: First of all thank you for your great Answer... But Just because of this line : public class ExternalMovie extends Sprite Flash says I can not add any line into the fla file because your class Extends an Sprite... and when I Change Sprite to MovieClip it starts to create another errors ... Is there any way to put your timeline part of script into that class...???

Comment: @SOmeon You need to learn and understand the concept of classes: https://www.kirupa.com/developer/as3/classes_as3_pg1.htm Also, I didn't bother to form the imports for the class, please do it on your own.

Comment: It seems there is no code on earth to loop swf files correctly ...):

Comment: Yes... I've used your code added some imports changed class Sprite to MovieClip.... then I got errors each time ... last time I got  this : Error: Error #2136: The SWF file file:///E|/loop/Test%5FExport%20%2D%20Copy/3%20Export/Untitled%2D1.swf contains invalid data.
 at ExternalMovie/frame1()

Comment: @SOmeon #2136 means you are doing something fundamentally wrong: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1005472

Comment: I copied first code in .as file with the name of ExternalMovie.as then copied second code in timeline and connect fla to .as file ....

Comment: @SOmeon Please explain this part in more details: "_...and connect fla to .as file_"

Comment: I just created a class from properties panel of Flash, named it to ExternalMovie, paste the code, and save  ExternalMovie .as file in same directory as fla file "that contains timeline code" Now the fla file has been connected to it's document class "ExternalMovie .as".

Comment: @SOmeon Yep, thought so. My class wasn't intended as a document root class, and that is the source of all the errors. What you need is to clear the document class, then in timeline code you just **import ExternalMovie;** to make it work. **P.S.** I updated my answer a bit.

Comment: I added " import ExternalMovie; " to fla timeline code and deleted class document link from fla; then #2136 error disappears, but this time nothing happens ... a blank white screen ... I think "import ExternalMovie;" doesn't import class...

Comment: @SOmeon Now put a lot of **trace(...)** statements to check what's going on. E.g. **trace(EML)** after **EML = new ExternalMovie;** will tel you if the class was instantiated properly.

Comment: Even with these updated codes I just get a blank output a blank screen!!! Sorry...

Comment: trace EML and L and M return : [object ExternalMovie]
[object Loader]
[object ExternalMovie]
[object dbmovie]

Comment: @SOmeon Nice, that means these objects exist and loaded properly. The question now, why don't you see anything. Trace now **M.parent**, **M.parent.parent** and so on up to the **stage**.

Comment: Can you please have a look at this question:            https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50021072/when-each-swf-finishes-it-never-loads-again

Comment: @SOmeon It's third-party classes so I have no idea what's inside and how they operate.